# How are heroes created?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

Skimming trough half the book time and again I didn't find it: under what circumstances how (ruleswise) are heroes created?

Comment: Are you referring to World of Darkness game Beast: The Primordial? Or to something else?

Comment: yepp that one it is chronicles of darkness now since yesterday (they renamed the game line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Storytellers discretion

See **Advancement** on p215 of Beast: The Primordial.

> When a Hero is created as a recurring antagonist in a 
>   chronicle or is being built to face down a group of experienced 
>   Beasts, the Storyteller should hand him appropriate Attributes, 
>   Skills, and other assets as necessary to challenge the player 
>   characters.

While keeping in mind several pointers of p206 with regards to **Heroic Traits** (like Hard to Kill, having Integrity, followers, Gifts...). So you can stat them out using normal character creation rules (looking at the example heroes here)or you have a rough concept and linked some fitting Gifts to that.

If it's more related to the "waking up" check p201-203.

Especially the following section:

> In game terms, the Heroes that stalk Beasts tend to have low Integrity ratings — their souls are weak and ill-defined. Being a Hero is, like being a Beast, something that a person is born with.

Comment: questin is mostly how they wake up. So there are no concrete rules tehre about HOW a hero comes into existence? (then my memory was from the pre change beast before the flair of the gameline was changed after the first round of feedback back then

Comment: yes, but there was no concrete information there how a hero itself comes into being. IF it is him coming into contact with a beats power or seeing someone suffer or if its like the beasts just getting nightmares time and again and suddenly they are heroes

Comment: @ThomasE. You should see them in a more latent manner. Until a hero encounters a Beast, he's for all intents & purposes a normal mortal. The first contact awakens something in him, that stirs him into action. Here also lies the big difference with hunters. Hunters can choose to ignore something with regard to their quarry (like not killing it), heroes can't (and if they can be convinced not do it, a whole can of worms are opened for them).